# Can not parse JSON with JavaScript parser. Square brackets

Tags: javascript, json

I using JavaScript JSON library to parse JSON encoded array, received via POST.

Here is my code:

```
    var itemsRequest = '[{"id":"142"},{"id":"152"}]';
    var items = JSON.parse(itemsRequest);
    for(var i = 0; i<items.count(); i++)
            {
                var item = items[i];
                alert(item.id);
            }
```

I am not sure why, but the parser is just not liking that. How can I get it to parse?

Comment: What does "not liking that" mean?  Do you get an error message in the console? What actually happens? What do you get for `console.log(items)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `items.length` instead of `items.count()`.

Answer (score 3):

An array doesn't have a `count` method. Use the `length` property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Rt4db/

Answer (score 1):

Below is the very good way to do:

```
var itemsRequest = '[{"id":"142"},{"id":"152"}]';
var items = eval(itemsRequest); //Converted to actual JSON data
for (var item in items) {
    alert(items[item]['id']);
}
```

Hope this is very helpful, thanks